# The string spectrum with several compactified dimensions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory, compactification

In his *String Theory Vol. I*  book, Polchinski wants to compute the string spectrum when $k$ of the 26 dimensions are compactified $$X^m \sim X^m + 2 \pi R, \quad 26 - k \leq m \leq 25 \, . \tag{8.4.1}$$
To do so, he gives two derivations, the first one being

> In the canonical approach, focus on the zero-mode contribution to the world-sheet action. Inserting
> $$ X^m(\sigma^1, \sigma^2) = x^m(\sigma^2) + w^m R \sigma^1 \tag{8.4.4} $$
> into the world-sheet action gives
> $$ L = \frac{1}{2 \alpha'} G_{m n} (\dot{x}^m \dot{x}^n + w^m w^n R^2) - \frac{i}{\alpha'} B_{m n} \dot{x}^m w^n R \tag{8.4.5} $$
> (...)
> The zero-mode contribution to the world-sheet Hamiltonian is
> $$ \frac{1}{2 \alpha'} G_{m n} (v^m v^n + w^m w^n R^2) \tag{8.4.8}  $$
> and the closed string mass is
> $$ m^2 = \frac{1}{2 \alpha' ^2} G_{m n} (v_L^m v_L^n + v_R^m v_R^n) + \frac{2}{\alpha'} (N + \tilde{N} - 2) \tag{8.4.9a} $$
> $$v_{L,R}^m = v^m \pm w^m R \tag{8.4.9b} $$

Here $v^m = \alpha' \frac{n_m}{R} - B_{m n} w^n R, $
$w^m$ is the winding number in the $m$ compactified direction, $n_m$ is the quantum number for the compatified momentum $p_m = n_m/R$, $B_{m n}$ is the antisymmetric tensor, $G_{m n}$ is the metric in the compactified coordinates, and $N$, $\tilde{N} \geq 0$ are integers.

To obtain this result, I am pretty sure Polchinski used
$$ m^2 = \frac{2}{\alpha'} (H + N + \tilde{N} - 2) \tag{1} $$
which follows from the physicality constraints $(4.3.31)$, $(4.3.32)$ and from $ L_0 + \tilde{L}_0 = H$

My question is : Why did Polchinski use only the zero-mode contribution to the Hamiltonian $(8.4.8)$ in equation $(1)$ ? How is it sufficient to consider only the zero-mode contribution when we want to compute the full spectrum ?